# How can I make graph readable using semPath

Tags: r-lavaan, semplot

How can I change my code that the graph is readable? I tried a few things but nothing seems to work. Here is the code:

```
Test.model <- '
MS =~ M_1 + M_2 + M_3
MV =~ M_4 + M_5 + M_6
MP =~ M_7 + M_8 + M_9
Monitor =~ 1*MS + MV + MP
CS =~ C_1 + C_2 + C_3
CV =~ C_4 + C_5 + C_6
CP =~ C_7 + C_8 + C_9
Correspondance =~ 1*CS + CV + CP
AS =~ A_1 + A_2 + A_3
AV =~ A_4 + A_5 + A_6 
AP =~ A_7 + A_8 + A_9
Adaption =~ 1*AS + AV + AP
Monitor ~~ Correspondance
Monitor ~~ Adaption
Correspondance ~~ Adaption
Careeradapt =~ 1*Monitor + Correspondance + Adaption'
```

```
rrslabels4<-c("M_1","M_2","M_3","M_4","M_5","M_6","M_7","M_8","M_9","C_1","C_2","C_3","C_4","C_5","C_6","C_7","C_8","C_9","A_1","A_2","A_3","A_4","A_5","A_6","A_7","A_8","A_9","stakeholders","value","progress","Monitor","stakeholders","value","progress","Correspondence","stakeholders","value","progress","Adaption", "Careeradapt")
semPaths(fit_TEST.model, whatLabels = "std", nodeLabels=rrslabels4,
         fixedStyle = (1), layout = "tree",style = "lisrel",label.norm=FALSE, label.scale=FALSE, edge.label.cex = .5, sizeMan = 8, sizeLat =3, sizeLat2 = 3, asize = 1, width=17, height=20)
```

Change the size etc